# Using string pointer to send a string through windows messages

Tags: string, delphi, pointers, delphi-7

I am trying to understand how are pointers to strings working. I have a code (not exactly original), which was written by somebody, and the person is not around here anymore, so I need to understand the idea of such usage.

```
var
  STR: string;
  pStr: ^string;
begin
  STR := 'Hello world';
  New(pStr);
  pStr^ := STR;

  PostMessage(Handle, WM_USER+1, wParam(pStr), 0);
end;
```

Now I know for sure, that a message handler gets the message and the pointer contains the string, which can be worked with, but what happens 'under the hood' of those operations **?**

I tried to make a small project. I thought, that assigning string to what a str pointer is pointing to would actually increase refcount of the original string and not make any copies of a string, but refcount remained 1 and it seems it did copy the contents.

So get the question, what happened? Calling `New` on a pointer allocates an empty string, right?
After assignment I tried to look at refcount/length of a string the pointer pointed to like this `PChar(@pStr^[1])[-8]` but it returned nonsense (14), and the length byte was also wrong.

Additionally the questioin is, is it safe using pointers in such a way to pass on the string through windows messaging?

Comment: Such data transfer is safe. But also risky, because if the recipient doesn't receive the message you're posting, or if that recipient doesn't release that allocated memory for some reason, you get a leak.

Comment: With WM_COPYDATA you can send any data to any recipient, for this its made. No need to create other solutions.

Comment: @TLama, what are the cases where the recipient wouldn't receive the message?

Comment: @Marcus, if the recipient doesn't exist or is destroyed before the message arrives e.g. This technique is unsafe. You just post a message and let it floating in a hope it arrives somewhere. If not, you have a leak.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`New(pStr)` allocates a `string` on the heap and returns a pointer to it. Because `string` is a managed type, the string is default initialized, to the empty string. Since a `string` is implemented as a pointer, what you fundamentally have is a pointer to a pointer.

You code is perfectly fine, so long as you only post the message to your own process. Since the payload of the message is a pointer, it only means something in the context of the virtual address space of your process. If you wanted to send to a different process you'd need an IPC mechanism.

Clearly in the code that pulls the message off the queue you need to dispose of the string. Something like this:

```
var
  p: ^string;
  str: string;
....
p := Pointer(wParam);
str := p^; 
Dispose(p);
```

Your code to query the reference count and the length is just wrong. Here's how to do it correctly:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

var
  pStr: ^string;
  p: PInteger;

begin
  New(pStr);
  pStr^ := 'Hello world';

  p := PInteger(pStr^);
  dec(p);
  Writeln(p^); // length
  dec(p);
  Writeln(p^); // ref count

  Readln;
end.
```

**Output:**

```
11
1
```

Comment: REMARK: Shouldn't it be `str := string(p^);` (`^` added)?

Comment: @alz str := p^; suffices